# ORA-30089 when execute CREATE TABLE with a DATE type field

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ddl

I'm getting the following error when creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTO(
    ID_EVENTO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_COMPLEJO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    N_COMISARIOS NUMBER,
    FECHA_EVENTO DATE,
    N_PARTICIPANTES NUMBER,
    DURACION INTERVAL,
    EQUIPAMIENTO VARCHAR2(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_COMPLEJO) REFERENCES COMPLEJO
);
```

I do not know if it is because of Oracle's permission to the user because I am on the desktop and here he does not let me create the table.

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 28 del comando :
CREATE TABLE EVENTO(
    ID_EVENTO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_COMPLEJO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    N_COMISARIOS NUMBER,
    FECHA_EVENTO DATE,
    N_PARTICIPANTES NUMBER,
    DURACION INTERVAL,
    EQUIPAMIENTO VARCHAR2(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_COMPLEJO) REFERENCES COMPLEJO
)
Informe de error -
ORA-30089: falta <campo datetime> o no es válido
30089. 00000 -  "missing or invalid <datetime field>"
*Cause:    A <datetime field> (YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND) is
           expected but not found, or a <datetime field> specified the
           <end field> in an <interval qualifier> is more significant
           than its <start field>.
*Action:
```

The other tables I create them well but with the `DATE` datatype I do not know if I'm getting it wrong ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement declares column `DURACION` as datatype `INTERVAL`

`INTERVAL` is not a valid datatype. You can either use `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`, or `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` (with various precision).

Consider, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTO(
    ID_EVENTO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_COMPLEJO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    N_COMISARIOS NUMBER,
    FECHA_EVENTO DATE,
    N_PARTICIPANTES NUMBER,
    DURACION INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH,
    EQUIPAMIENTO VARCHAR2(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_COMPLEJO) REFERENCES COMPLEJO
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94b3e4977b6bcd9480a8bff26a3b21c3)**

Reference: [Oracle datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020).

Answer (score 0):

The type  INTERVAL in duration field is not valid, it doesn't exist as a datatype. I recommend you use a start date and end date, which is better and can provide much better information. Working with intervals can bring a lot of issues in the future.

```
 CREATE TABLE EVENTO(
    ID_EVENTO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_COMPLEJO NUMBER NOT NULL,
    N_COMISARIOS NUMBER,
    FECHA_EVENTO DATE,
    N_PARTICIPANTES NUMBER,
    FECHA_INICIO DATE,
    FECHA_FIN DATE,
    EQUIPAMIENTO VARCHAR2(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_COMPLEJO) REFERENCES COMPLEJO
)
```